# LC-3: BLKW ho to specify memory location to store data at?

Tags: memory, store, lc3

In LC-3 when you use BLKW how do you initialize the block of memory to be at location x3102 instead of the next available memory location?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make a side note that all the memory of the 16-bit address space is there for you to use, according to the memory map (e.g. at least in the range x3000-xFDFF), and, it is initialized to zero; you can use it at will.

Generally speaking, the LC-3 assemblers don't allow multiple .ORIG directives throughout the file, instead, they require one at the beginning of the file.  If they did allow subsequent .ORIG directives, this would be a way to accomplish what you're asking about.

But even if they did, frequently, we'd run into instruction offset encoding limitations.  So there's an alternate solution I'll show below.

But first, let's look at the instruction offset/immediate encoding limitations.

The usual data memory access instruction formats have a very limited offset, only 9 bits worth (+/- about 256), and the offset is pc-relative.  So, for example, the following won't work:

```
      .ORIG x3000

      LEA R0, TESTA
      LD R1, TESTA

      LEA R2, TESTB         ; will get an error due to instruction offset encoding limitation
      LD R3, TESTB          ; will get an error due to instruction offset encoding limitation

      HALT

    TESTA
      .FILL #1234

      .BLKW xFA             ; exactly enough padding to relocate TESTB to x3100

    TESTB
       .FILL #4321          ; which we can initialize with a non-zero value

      .END
```

This illustrative: while this will successfully place `TESTB` at x3100, it cannot be reached by the either the `LEA` or the `LD` instructions due to the limited 9-bit pc-relative displacement.

*(There is also the other practical limitation that as instructions are added the `.BLKW` operand has to shrink in size, which is clearly painful — this aspect would have been eliminated by supporting a `.ORIG` directive within.)*

So, the alternative for large blocks and other such is to resort to using zero-initialized memory, and referencing this other memory using pointer variables nearby: using `LD` to load an address, rather than `LEA`, and `LDI` to access a value rather than `LD`.

```
      .ORIG x3000

      LEA R0, TESTA
      LD R1, TESTA

      LD R2, TESTBRef       ; will put x3100 into R3
      LDI R3, TESTBRef      ; will access the memory value at address x3100..

      HALT

    TESTA
      .FILL #1234

    TESTBRef                ; a nearby data pointer, that points using the full 16-bits
      .FILL x3100

      .END
```

In the latter, above, there is no declaration to reserve storage at `x3100`, nor can we initialize that storage at `x3100` with non-zero initialization (e.g. no strings, no pre-defined arrays).

A data-to-data pointer, `TESTBRef` is used.  Unlike code-to-code/data references (i.e. *instructions* referencing code or data), data-to-code/data 
(i.e. *data* referencing code or data) pointers have all 16-bits available for pointing.

So, once we use this approach, of simply using other memory, we forgo the automatic placement of labels after other labels (for those other areas), and also forgo non-zero initialization.

---

Some LC-3 assemblers will allow multiple files, and these each allow their own `.ORIG` directive — so by using multiple files, we can place code&data at varied locations in the address space.  However, the code-to-data instruction offset encoding limits still apply, and so, you'll likely end up managing other such memory areas manually anyway, and using data pointers as well.

---

Note that the JSR instruction has an 11-bit offset so code-to-code references can reach farther than code-to-data references.